# Can Android 4.1 Jelly Bean open MS-office and PDF files?

Tags: applications, 4.1-jelly-bean, ms-office

I want to buy a HCL tablet that have Android 4.1 Jelly Bean. I want to know if it can open MS-office and PDF files.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't open MS-Office and PDF files directly from Android.

You have to install a third party app.

A few nice apps available in market for this:

- [WPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wps.moffice_eng)
- [Microsoft Office Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.officehub)

Answer (score 0):

Another good solution is OfficeSuite. It opens and edits Microsoft office documents. But I would recommend something else if that's what you want to do with it.